# Child process prints on redirected stdout, parent never receives

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I'm a beginner when it comes to C and I'm writing this program where I have an array at the beginning and have to fork twice so that I have two child processes. Each child process gets half of the parent's array and executes the program based on it, making it recursive.

When a child gets an array containing only one element, that element is printed on stdout and then it exits.

Each parent then reads what its two children send on stdout and makes a calculation based on it. The result of the calculation is an array that is then being printed also on the stdout for the parent's parent's calculation.

What's not working:
I'm getting to the end of the recursion and printing out the value of the 1-element array in each child, but the parent can't seem to read it.
It never enters the while loop where I'm using fgets().

This is the part in parent where I'm splitting the array in two. Here I'm also giving out the value (without doing anything else) in case I get an array with one value:

```
while( fgets(strBuffer, sizeof(strBuffer), stdin)!= NULL){

  if(counter % 2 == 0){

    if(evenCounter == evenMax){
      evenMax++;
      evenBuffer = (char**) realloc(evenBuffer, evenMax * 
      sizeof(char*));

   }if(evenBuffer == NULL){
     fprintf(stderr, "error reallocating evenBuffer\n");
     exit(1);
   }

    evenBuffer[evenCounter] = (char*) malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(evenBuffer[evenCounter], strBuffer);
    evenCounter += 1;

  } else {

    if(oddCounter == oddMax){
      oddMax ++;
      oddBuffer = (char**) realloc(oddBuffer, oddMax * 
            sizeof(char*));
    }if(oddBuffer == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "error reallocating oddBuffer\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    oddBuffer[oddCounter] = (char*) malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(oddBuffer[oddCounter], strBuffer);
    ddCounter += 1;
  }

  counter ++;

}

if(counter == 1){
  fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", evenBuffer[0]);
  //  fprintf(stderr, "LAAAAST %s\n", evenBuffer[0]);
  fflush(stdout);
  exit(0);
}


if(oddCounter != evenCounter){
  fprintf(stderr, "evenCounter size:%d, oddCounter:%d\n", 
  evenCounter, oddCounter);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Here's the code part where the children are created and the pipes are created and redirected.

```
  int k1pipe_from[2];
  int k1pipe_to[2];
  pipe(k1pipe_from);
  pipe(k1pipe_to);

  int k2pipe_from[2];
  int k2pipe_to[2];
  pipe(k2pipe_from);
  pipe(k2pipe_to);

  pid_t pid = fork();
  pid_t pid2;

 switch(pid){
  case -1:
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  case 0://child 1
    fprintf(stderr, "Child 1 created, pid: %d\n", getpid());

    close(k2pipe_from[1]);
    close(k2pipe_to[0]);

    close(k1pipe_from[1]);
    close(k1pipe_to[0]);

    dup2(k1pipe_from[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(k1pipe_from[0]);
    dup2(k1pipe_to[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(k1pipe_to[1]);

    fflush(stdout);
    execl("forkFFT", "forkFFT", NULL);
    break;
 default:
   close(k1pipe_to[1]);
   close(k1pipe_from[0]);
   fflush(stdout);
}

pid2 = fork();
switch(pid2){
  case -1:
   fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork!\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  case 0://child 2
   close(k1pipe_from[1]);
   close(k1pipe_to[0]);
   close(k2pipe_from[1]);
   close(k2pipe_to[0]);

   dup2(k2pipe_from[0], STDIN_FILENO);
   close(k2pipe_from[0]);
   dup2(k2pipe_to[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
   close(k2pipe_to[1]);
   fflush(stdout);

   execl("forkFFT", "forkFFT", NULL);
   break;
  default:
   close(k2pipe_to[1]);
   close(k2pipe_from[0]);
}
```

Here's the part where I'm reading what one of the child processes has written on its redirected stdout.

```
FILE* k1File = fdopen(k1pipe_to[0], "r+");
char r1Buffer[1000];
evenResCounter = 0;
char* pend1;

while(fgets(r1Buffer, strlen(r1Buffer), k1File) != NULL){
  double real = (double) strtof(r1Buffer, &pend1);
  double img = 0.00;
  if(pend1 != NULL){
    img = (double) strtof(pend1, NULL);
  }

  evenRes[evenResCounter] = real + img * I;

  evenResCounter ++;

}

close(k1pipe_to[0]);
```

Here's the part with the calculation, after which the parent prints out the calculated array:

```
double pi = 3.141592654;
int total_elem = evenResCounter + oddResCounter;
double complex transArray[total_elem];
int k = 0;
int half = total_elem/2;

while(k <= half){
  transArray[k] = evenRes[k] + (cos(-2*pi/total_elem*k) + I * sin(-2*pi/total_elem*k)) * oddRes[k];
  transArray[k + half] = evenRes[k] - (cos(-2*pi/total_elem*k) + I * sin(-2*pi/total_elem*k)) * oddRes[k];
  k++;
}

int final_counter = 0;
while(final_counter != total_elem){
  fprintf(stdout, "%f %f*i\n", creal(transArray[final_counter]), cimag(transArray[final_counter]));
}
```

Would be super grateful for any help.

Comment: Not seeing a print or write anywhere.

Comment: @stark added the rest of the code, the prints are there
first when it reaches the 1-element-array case, and then after the calculation part

Comment: In child 1, you should have 8 close (2 closes for each of 4 pipes) — with two of the closes coming after the `dup2()` calls as shown (that much is correct).  Similarly in child 2.  I find the sequencing of your closes non-obvious; I'd deal with both ends of each unused pipe in consecutive steps (`close(k2pipe_from[0]); close(k2pipe_from[1]);` in child 1, for example).  I lose track of what you've closed and not closed — I think the missing closes for child 1 are `close(k2pipe_from[0]); close(k2pipe_to[1]);`.

Comment: How much the missing closes matter in this case is a separate question; I've not looked into that at all.  But in general, if you don't close the unused ends of pipes (especially the write end of a pipe), then processes won't get EOF when reading from the pipe because some unexpected process could still write to the pipe, but isn't going to write to it.  This is particularly a problem if a parent process holds the pipes open when the children rely on detecting EOF to know when to finish.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm gonna look into that
Kinda solved the reading from children, the problem is that I'm reading only from half of them now and I think it might be a pipe issue

Answer (score 0):

1. You should get `pipe` for child send message to parent
2. In child, redirect `stdout` to `pipe`, recursive or just output data
3. In parent, redirect `stdin` to `pipe`, get data, if in `main process`, call `calculation()`, else just call `output_data()`

The following code just get the sum of each data, you could change it in `calculation()`:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int sum = 0;

void output_data(int data) {
  printf("%d\n", data);
}

void calculation(int data) {
  sum += data;
}

void child(int* array, int left, int right, bool in_main_process) {
  if (left == right)
    exit(0);
  if (left + 1 == right) {
    in_main_process ? calculation(array[left]) : output_data(array[left]);
    exit(0);
  }

  int mid = (left + right) / 2;

  int pipe_fd_1[2];
  pipe(pipe_fd_1);

  if (fork() == 0) { // child 1
    close(pipe_fd_1[0]);
    dup2(pipe_fd_1[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipe_fd_1[1]);
    child(array, left, mid, false);
    exit(1);
  }

  int pipe_fd_2[2];
  pipe(pipe_fd_2);
  if (fork() == 0) { // child 2
    close(pipe_fd_2[0]);
    dup2(pipe_fd_2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipe_fd_2[1]);
    child(array, mid, right, false);
    exit(1);
  }

  close(pipe_fd_1[1]);
  dup2(pipe_fd_1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
  close(pipe_fd_1[0]);

  int data;
  while (scanf("%d", &data) == 1)
    in_main_process ? calculation(data) : output_data(data);

  close(pipe_fd_2[1]);
  dup2(pipe_fd_2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
  close(pipe_fd_2[0]);

  while (scanf("%d", &data) == 1)
    in_main_process ? calculation(data) : output_data(data);
}

int main() {
  int array[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

  int left  = 0;
  int right = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
  child(array, left, right, true);
  printf("%d\n", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping
The mistake was in the fgets() call as i was storing in an empty buffer using strlen(buffer) instead of sizeof(buffer)
But I'm gonna take a look at the pipes again since I now stumbled into another apparently pipe-related problem